# GCC 4.4/4.5 unique_ptr not work for unordered_set/unordered_map

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++11

Is there any place I can confirm this?  I am not sure if it is the problem of GCC or my code.  For example, the following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_set<unique_ptr<int> > s;
    unique_ptr<int> p(new int(0));
    s.insert(move(p));
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is too big and I don't want to put here.  GCC version is 4.5.3, compiling flag is -std=gnu++0x.  Also tested on 4.4.5.

Comment: This is probably because `std::hash` is not specialised for `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Mankarse There is a specialization for it, but confusingly it appears in 20.7.2.6 Smart pointer hash support [util.smartptr.hash] (n3290) right after the specs for `std::shared_ptr`, somewhat far away from `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: N.B. you should say `std::move` not `move`, you don't want ADL to find a different function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct.  This is a known issue in GCC 4.5.  It has been fixed in 4.6.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436 .  It affects ordered containers too (std::map, std::set etc).  Probably the easiest workaround (at a slight performance penalty) would be to use std::shared_ptr instead of std::unique_ptr.

Answer (score 8):

GCC 4.6.1 accepts your code as is and I see nothing wrong with it (i.e. the value_type of an associative container is required to be EmplaceInsertable and `std::unique_ptr` does not prevent that). Presumably this is a deficiency in GCC 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that this is an issue with GCC 4.4.5. Attempting to insert a unique_ptr into an std::set results in a long compiler error message which alludes to the fact that some function in the STL attempted to copy the unique_ptr:

> error: deleted function [unique_ptr's copy ctor]... used here
>   [g++-v4/bits/stl_tree.h:136].

The STL function in question is part of the internal tree structure of several STL classes, including std::set. It is also within a "__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__" ifdef, which presumably  means that GCC 4.4 doesn't officially support what we're trying to do.

If you don't want to upgrade to GCC 4.6 you could always wrap an std::vector and strategically check for and remove duplicates at certain points in your code.